# How could an all-powerful god oppose an all-powerful god?

Tags: gods

In Zoroastrianism, the precursor to modern Christianity and Judaism, there were two all-powerful gods, one good and one evil. Neither could defeat the either. In a setting like this, what are some things that a could keep two such beings in constant gridlock?

Note: Because both being all-powerful, could easily will things to change. But they don't, for some reason of the other one... what could one hold over the other? What houses of cards would each not want to upset? Why would they both tolerate the same balance?

I'm looking for ideas of why an evil and good god would at LEAST be able to agree on a balance, if not both consider the situation optimal.

Comment: Because they're alter egos of the same God , they cannot exist individually

Comment: This is a philosophy question, not WB.

Comment: "*I'm looking for ideas of why an evil and good god would at LEAST be able to agree on a balance.*" They **don't agree** on a balance; it's thrust upon them by the nature of their equal and opposing power.

Comment: @RonJohn Something being thrust upon them seems counter to the all-powerful concept. The beings I have in my story are both absolute, and the inability to eliminate eachother would be counter to their absoluteness.

Comment: Maybe "thrust upon" can be misinterpreted as as external force doing something.  The balance **is a consequence of** their equal and opposing power.

Comment: @RonJohn is right - this is a philosophy question. Even a simple logical (instead of semantic) analysis will reveal that a maximum of one "all-powerful" god can exist in one universe. If another entity of similar power exists, then neither can truly be "all-powerful."  Super-powerful, sure. Mega-powerful, yes. Powerful-beyond-our-comprehension, yes. But not all-powerful. Revise the assumptions (and description) to eliminate the paradox, or consider the question perhaps more appropriate for Philosophy SE or Religion SE.

Comment: @user535733 I'm asking for the purpose of a world I'm building, so philosophy is definitely the wrong area to ask. I'd get answers like "what is a god" rather than "they came to see eye-to-eye because..."
That said, actually, being less simple with your logical analysis says an infinite number of all-powerful gods could exist, because if an all-powerful god existed, it could also reach the absolute compromise. Which means any number of all-powerful gods would be able to resolve things with eachother.

Comment: One would discover that one of these two all-powerful gods was not actually all-powerful.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the conflict between God and the Devil through the eyes of the Abrahamic faiths (Judaism, Christianity, Islam) and their sacred texts, the obvious point of dispute between them is the power to control the lives of those on Earth. Taking a more Catholic (or at least modern Christianity) bent, the concepts of Heaven and Hell make it clear that both deities are competing for souls to populate their non-earthly domains.

Heading over to the East, and we see this idea of competition manifested in religions like [Taoism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taoism) which refers to the balance between Ying and Yang energies.

In all these cases, the absence of one is the absence of both. They almost serve to contrast the other in many cases and it's rare to find a description of either God or the Devil in religious writings that doesn't in some (even indirect way) reference the other.

If we carry this on to the idea of Heaven and Hell, it may well be that;

1) Both 'Gods' need the inflow of souls into their domains in order to survive
2) Both agree that destroying the source of souls on Earth means their mutual destruction

In such a case, balance would be preferable to annihilation. After all, half of something is always better than all of nothing. This would be especially so in a concept where the Gods you describe didn't actually *create* the universe.

They may be omnipotent, but they may have also just found the Earth when they both came to exist. In point of fact, they may have come to exist once numbers of humans capable of reason reached a critical mass necessary for their manifestation.

If that was the case, their ability to recreate the Earth may never have been tested, and as such it's the one source of their power that can't be messed with. If the power isn't related to Heaven and Hell at all, but the relative number of living people who act in alignment with one or the other God, then destroying the earth may well destroy both Gods before they have time to recreate it.

Such a model assumes of course that Gods can't 'store' their power. They have no battery for their omnipotence, and therefore either need the souls in their domains OR the souls alive but in alignment with their own ideals to survive. If one or the other found a way to store away energy (even for a short time) to operate independently of the souls on or from earth, all bets would be off.

Answer (score 2):

### Collateral Damage

Both deities might nurture the belief that they could best their rival. However, even the smallest direct struggles renders the world a ruin. It's possible that the two engaged for countless ages in short-term universes that were turned to dust by conflict. The two deities could have come to have realized before this stable universe came into being that, if they want to enjoy their mutual creation, they need to back off.

### Wisdom

Both deities might have sufficient wisdom to recognize their opposite brings something irreplaceable to the table. While Good might wish Evil could bring its unique talents to bear the way It wishes, both deities might realize things are better with their opposite.

Answer (score 0):

In most mythology, conflicts between gods seem impractical. (See Egyptian mythology).

That being said, if you're looking for a practical basis for why they could be in gridlock. It might be best to think of it not as gridlock, but as a never ending game of tit for tat like Loki and Thor. A constant doing and undoing of mischief. 
They may tolerate this on the basis that they are not supreme in their pantheon (if Ares actually killed Athena, or if Demeter killed Hades, Zeus would not be pleased). 
They might consider it optimal if they get to keep to themselves as a result. I.e. Poseidon takes the ocean and Hades the underworld and never the two shall meet.

Comment: If I recall, the egyptian gods weren't all-powerful. This is more the zoraster/christian/jewish idea of a god of an all-powerful being.

Comment: All powerful sounds highly subjective, AM still required the good spirits to help him in his acts and there was an opposing force in the universe he created. Or is the basis for disagreement that he was capable of creating the universe by himself, whereas in the Egyptian pantheon, responsibilities are split? If that is the case, I understand entirely. The Egyptian pantheon, as an entity, is "all powerful", but we're only speaking of a case where one entity may will anything they want within the universe they created?